# getting scheme java.lang.NullPointerException: scheme while trying to fake a server call in my service

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest

I have a service class in my project and I want to test one of its methods that is performing an api call, so I want to catch this call and return something fake so I can test my method, it looks like this:

```
class MyService @Inject()(implicit config: Configuration, wsClient: WSClient) {

  def methodToTest(list: List[String]): Future[Either[BadRequestResponse, Unit]] = {
    wsClient.url(url).withHeaders(("Content-Type", "application/json")).post(write(list)).map { response =>
      response.status match {
        case Status.OK =>
          Right(logger.debug("Everything is OK!"))
        case Status.BAD_REQUEST =>
          Left(parse(response.body).extract[BadRequestResponse])
        case _ =>
          val ex = new RuntimeException(s"Failed with status: ${response.status} body: ${response.body}")
          logger.error(s"Service failed: ", ex)
          throw ex
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and now in my test class I go:

```
class MyServiceTest extends FreeSpec with ShouldMatchers with OneAppPerSuite with ScalaFutures with WsScalaTestClient {

  implicit lazy val materializer: Materializer = app.materializer
  lazy val config: Configuration = app.injector.instanceOf[Configuration]
  lazy val myService = app.injector.instanceOf[MyService]

  "My Service Tests" - {

    "Should behave as im expecting" in {
      Server.withRouter() {
        case POST(p"/fake/api/in/conf") => Action { request =>
          Results.Ok
        }
      } { implicit port =>
        WsTestClient.withClient { implicit client =>

          whenReady(myService.methodToTest(List("1","2","3"))) { res =>
            res.isRight shouldBe true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I get this error:

```
scheme java.lang.NullPointerException: scheme
```

also tried put under client => :

```
val myService = new MyService {
         implicit val config: Configuration = configuration
         implicit val ws: WSClient = client
      }
```

but got some other error that I dont have enough arguments in the constructor...

why is it not working?

if there is a better nd simpler way to fake this api call i will love to hear it :)

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Server.withRouter` may not be exactly what you want. It creates a server and bound it to a random port, per instance (unless you specify the port). It also creates its own instance of application which will be *disconnected* from the app you used to instantiate the service.

Another thing is that the injected `WSClient` **do not** works relative to your application. You need to use the `client` which is passed to `WsTestClient.withClient` block instead. So, you should do something like:

```
class MyServiceTest extends FreeSpec with ShouldMatchers with OneAppPerSuite with ScalaFutures with WsScalaTestClient {

  implicit lazy val materializer: Materializer = app.materializer
  lazy val config: Configuration = app.injector.instanceOf[Configuration]

  "My Service Tests" - {

    "Should behave as im expecting" in {
      Server.withRouter() {
        case POST(p"/fake/api/in/conf") => Action { request =>
          Results.Ok
        }
      } { implicit port =>
        WsTestClient.withClient { implicit client =>

          // Use the client "instrumented" by Play. It will
          // handle the relative aspect of the url.
          val myService = new MyService(client, config)

          whenReady(myService.methodToTest(List("1","2","3"))) { res =>
            res.isRight shouldBe true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```